# Change Alt Value from another Input Field's value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I have two input fields within a form and would like that the value of the first input field is added to the alt property of the second input field using onkeyup.

How can it be done using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using jQuery

```
$('#field1').keyup(function(){
  $('#field2').attr('alt', $(this).val());
});
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: I didnt see any jquery tag

Comment: I know ... that's just how I'd do it, and the majority of websites these days will have jQuery included anyway.  It can obviously be done using plain JS, just not as succinctly.